# Unit testing and high-order functions in Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

So i have a base class:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseService<M : MyMetric>(private val otherService: OtherService) {

    abstract fun <T> monitor(metric: M, action: () -> T): T

    protected fun <T> monitorDefault(metric: M, action: () -> T): T {
        val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()
        return try {
            notifyEvent(metric.total)
            val result = action()
            notifyEvent(metric.success)
            result
        } catch (e: CommonException) {
            //handling
        }
    }
```

and simple implementation:

```kotlin
class PrintMetricService(otherService: OtherService): BaseService<PrintMetric>(otherService) {

    override fun <T> monitor(metric: PrintMetric, action: () -> T) : T {
        return monitorDefault(metric, action)
    }
}
```

then i use this method:

```kotlin
@Service
class PrintReportService(private val reportService: ReportService,
                         private val metricService: MetricService<PrintMetric>) {

    fun getReport(): String {
 
        return metricService.monitor(PrintMetric) {
            val response = try {
                    reportService.renderPdf(jsonRequest, TEMPLATE_CODE, channel)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    throw CommonException(PRINT_SERVICE_ERROR_EXCEPTION_CODE)
                }
            response.body.data!!
        }
    }
```

now I want to write a unit test for `getReport()` (we use TestNg and mockito in project):

```kotlin
class PrintReportServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var printReportService: PrintReportServiceImpl

    @Mock
    private lateinit var reportService: ReportService

    @Mock
    private lateinit var metricService: PrintMetricService


    @BeforeMethod
    fun setUp() {
        openMocks(this)

        whenever(reportService.renderPdf().thenReturn("response (base64)")
    }

    @Test
    fun getReportTest() {
        val report = printReportService.getReport()
        assertNotNull(report)
    }
}
```

the test crashes with an error:  `java.lang.AssertionError: expected object to not be null`
But if i add `inline` when override `monitor(metric: M, action: () -> T)` in `PrintMetricService` the test will pass. What could be the problem? Is this a feature of the high-order functions in Kotlin?

Comment: Why do you mock the services that you want to test? You should only mock dependencies, but not the code under test

Comment: should I use @Spy in this case?

Comment: I mean you should just create instances of the things you want to test normally, and use mocks when you need to inject dependencies into it. Here you could instantiate `PrintMetricService()` and `PrintReportService()` yourself depending on which one you're testing, and passing whatever mocks you need to their constructor